# JSP is servlet but there is no function called doGet() or doPost() in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, web

I am a beginner in servlet/JSP.
I have read that JSP is actually a servlet (after the container transfer the JSP file into a Java source code and compiled it). 
But in the servlet, there is always at least one of the doGet() and doPost(). In JSP, I do not write any code to override the doGet() or doPost(). What I write is just below:

```
<%@ page import="com.example.*, java.util.*" %>
<html>
<body>
the page count is:
<%=
Counter.getCount()
%>
</body>
</html>
```

I know the above code will be changed to java code like:

```
public void _jspService(){
    out.println(......)
}
```

But I do not see the doGet() or doPost().
So, where is doGet() and doPost() in the JSP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the `javax.servlet.Servlet` interface you will see that it doesn't actually have any `doXXX` methods, all the requests are actually handled in:
 `public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res)`.

The `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet` class implements this method, defines all the `doXXX` methods and calls:
`protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)` this method actually classifies http requests by type and calls the `doXXX` methods which you ovveride in your `Servlet`.

`org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase` is the base class for all JSP-generated servlets (this is tomcat implementation) and it overrides `HttpServlet.service` method that does the classification. All this method does is calling `_jspService` which is implemented in the compiled JSP.

If you want to know the type of the http request in your JSP you can use [request.getMethod()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getMethod--).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the entire class, you'll see that it extends an internal, implementation dependent parent class, which, inevitably, inherits from Servlet. One of these parent classes will implement the `doGet` and `doPost` methods, and those will, inevitably, call the `_jspService` method of the generated JSP class.

Here's an example from Glassfish:

```
package org.apache.jsp;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.jsp.*;

public final class x_jsp extends org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase
    implements org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspSourceDependent {
```

Comment: So when a request comes, the parent class will decide to call doPost() or doGet(). If it chooses the doPost(), for example, then the doPost() will call the _jspService() that I just implemented? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? From what I could see so far it's called directly from the service method.

Comment: This is not correct, `_jspService` is called directly from `service` `doPost` and `doGet` have absolutely nothing to do with jsp pages.

Answer (score 0):

Those methods will be present in parent class (HttpServlet)